# Google Analytics V4 API - Right Syntax for dynamicSegment and metricFilter

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Trying (using Python) to create dynamic segment to get all sessions who completed a specific goal.
Current syntax I'm using for the metricFIlter:

```
"metricFilter":
                  {
                    "metricName":"ga:goal3Completions",
                    "operator":"NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN",
                    "comparisonValue":[0]
                  }
```

I've also tried other options like ['0'], 0, '0' but with no success.
Here is the response error I'm getting:

```
"Invalid value at 'report_requests[0].segments[0].dynamic_segment.session_segment.segment_filters[0].simple_segment.or_filters_for_segment.segment_filter_clauses[0].metric_filter.operator' (TYPE_ENUM), "NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN""
```

Any suggestions how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The operator **NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN** is only valid for filtering dimensions, not metrics.

```
"metricFilterClauses" : [
    {   
        "filters" : [
            {
                "metricName" : "ga:goal3Completions",
                "operator":"GREATER_THAN",
                "comparisonValue": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

You can find a list of operators in the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#metricfilterclause).

Comment: I'm using this solution as well. I wanted to start using dynamic segments so I was trying to understand the syntax.

Comment: The operator NUMERIC_GREATER_THAN is only valid for filtering dimensions, not metrics.